# Powershell variable initialization affect function return?

Tags: powershell, initialization

Today I've found very strange behaviour which for me doesn't have any logic. In my one machine this code works as I expected but in two more machines I reproduce

```
function Set-XXX {param([String] $variableName) 
    [string]$vw;
    $vw = $variableName;
    return $vw;
}
```

When I execute this function I've strange result as `Object[]` not as I expected like `string`.

```
PS C:\Users\Robert> $ve = Set-XXX -variableName "eeee"
PS C:\Users\Robert> $ve.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
PS C:\Users\Robert> $ve[0]
PS C:\Users\Robert> $ve[1]
eeee
```

When I set `$vw` with empty string: `[string]$vw = ''` resulting type is `string` and there is no problem. Can anybody explain me why this happen?

```
PS C:\Users\Robert> function Set-XXX {param([String] $variableName)
>>     [string]$vw= '';
>>     $vw = $variableName;
>>     return $vw;
>> }
PS C:\Users\Robert> $vex = Set-XXX -variableName "eeee"
PS C:\Users\Robert> $vex
eeee
PS C:\Users\Robert> $vex.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


PS C:\Users\Robert> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.546
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.546
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Why Powershell doesn't respect variable declaration `[string]` and is trying to return `Object[]` ?

Comment: PowerShell doesn't have variable _declarations_ like many other languages, so this: `[string]$vw`, is treated as a cast operation - which will return an empty string if `vw` isn't already assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return keyword is reduntant in PowerShell, anything inside a function that gives output will be returned by the function.

Thus in your function two things are returned, first `$vw` which at that time is an empty string, then `$vw` again which by now has a value.

Basically you're getting an array because your function is returning two objects/values.

Try running `([string]$null).GetType()` and you'll see a null variable cast as a string will return an empty string.

Just remove

```
[string]$vw;
```

which has no real point in the function.

Comment: In more complex function how to set variable to be accessed in many areas? I mean that `$someVar` will be used in many places.

Comment: Do you mean setting a variable that will be used outside the function or in several places inside the function?`In either case I think this is probably better as a separate question (do search first though, the answer could very well be on Stack Overflow already).

Comment: I mean that I have variable that is in function only but it can be initialized in different code places. I need to check if for example string was initialized and if not do some extra work

Comment: Ask it as a new question and I'll take a look!